# Eclipse Neon/Mars is very slow/hangs on a fresh 16.04 install and Upgrade

Tags: eclipse, 16.04

Eclipse Mars/Neon running very slow after upgrading to xenial

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That works fine, you can also set:

```
--launcher.GTK_version 2
```

in the beginning of your `eclipse.ini` file.

This way if you have a `.desktop` shortuct it will also work automatically

Comment: helps to speed up in 14.04 too

Comment: How does it help in increasing the speed?

Comment: I also noticed that with nvidia cards this doesn't help too much. In addition you need the latest nvidia drivers (which on 16.04 will cause tearing). I set nvidia prime to power-safe mode to use the integrated chip and then apply above action and that works fine for all versions of eclipse that i have tried

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution when I was on my main machine, I'm now typing this on my tablet, so please excuse the brevity. If you type export SWT_GTK3=0 before invoking eclipse from a terminal, you will load quickly. Googling for 'eclipse' and 'SWT_GTK3' will find the bug report that led me to the solution.

Comment: Thanks Nick, It is working fine with env SWT_GTK3=0, I found existing bug in [java-common package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1552764) where other users suggested same workaround.

Comment: This does not help on the recent Ubuntu Mate distribution for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

open terminal and type following command

```
 export SWT_GTK3=0
```

add this to your ~/.profile file to make it persistent across logins (you'll need to logout and log back in to be able to start eclipse from shortcut)

then go to your eclipse folder and search for eclipse.ini file
Right click anywhere in the folder and choose "open in terminal" and type following command in terminal

```
sudo gedit eclipse.ini
```

and add the following line before --launcher.appendVmargs

```
--launcher.GTK_version 2
```

Search in the file for 256 and replace it with 1024